# Is there a 64-bit version of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 64bit, autocad-map

32-bit ArcMap is not playing well with 64-bit AutoCAD Map

Comment: How are they conflicting?  How are they supposed to be interacting?

Comment: This has now shown up in at least two different review queues - low quality and close - unclear what is being asked. Low quality is a matter of opinion and should be addressed by voting on the question, up or down. "Is there a 64bit version of ArcMap?" seems pretty clear to me and is the question being asked - not 'why aren't Arc and ACAD getting along'. If the asker would like to rephrase or expand their question to try and troubleshoot specific issues they're having, that's fine and as written it would be unclear. But as written it's just a short, simple question to be dealt with via votes.

Comment: There was mumblings about 10.3 being offered as 64 bit but it looks like that didn't happen... perhaps in the next version will be offered as 32/64 bit but don't hold your breath. It would be far simpler to get 32bit AutoCAD. What is it about them that isn't getting along? is there a shared DLL, is there an interoperablility issue, is there a link that can't be established?

Comment: No "perhaps" about it, @MichaelMiles-Stimson; I don't see *any* chance that Desktop will be rewritten as a 64-bit application suite.

Comment: @Vince I'll reserve my opinion on that and multi-threading too (been waiting for that since the early 2k's). Both would take a **huge** rewrite at the lowest level and as ArcGis is a huge suite of source code and a vast number of extensions that would also need to be extensively rewritten, there's no doubt this is a big task... but then again Esri is a large company with a lot of paying customers (lots of them requesting 64 bit mult-threading).... just saying.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a 64-bit version although you can add in [64 bit background processing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002100000040000000).    ESRI released [ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/), which is a 64 bit program.  Have a look at the site for licensing and other details surrounding the program.  It isn't a replacement for ArcMap, but you may find you're able to use a lot of the same functionality in it that you would with ArcMap.

The 64 bit background processing is a good start if you are able to run items in the background.  If speed is your worry, you are also able to utilize `ArcPy` modules in stand-alone python scripts as long as you have appropriate licensing.